# Printing incorrect output

Tags: c

I am on a mission on creating a simple battleship game in C. However, as I've done as asked - I am getting incorrect output. What am I missing?

You can find describtion of the mission here: http://pastebin.com/nTAvKgjA

Here is my function:

```
void print_field(void)
{

    int row_index = 0, col_index = 0;
    int num_rows = 10, num_cols = 10;

    for (row_index = 0; row_index < num_rows; row_index++)
    {
        for (col_index = 0; col_index < num_cols; col_index++)
        {
            if(is_visible(row_index, col_index) != 0) 
            {  
                printf("%c", is_ship(row_index, col_index));
            }
            else
            {
                putchar('?');
            }
        }

        putchar ('\n');
    }

    putchar ('\n');
}
```

It's working, when I test it manually. However, when the testing is done online - I'm getting errors. Please check it from here:  http://pastebin.com/xrzRy0ge

So what am I missing? This is so frustrating...

Comment: Post an errors here. If a service goes down, we have no way of helping.

Comment: Without knowing what the functions you call do all anyone can do is guess.  You're going to need to post more code.

Comment: Added errors in-site and linked more code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Interesting.  It looks like you and the test program have a different coordinate system.  Your result and the reference result are identical if you flip both axis.

Comment: Yes, in the "description" linked by OP the functions have signature `is_visible(x,y)` while OP uses `is_visible(row_index, col_index)`, so he's probably transposing the matrix...

Comment: Can you explain better?

Comment: If you examine your output and look at the left-most column, you'll see it's identical to the reference top line.  So, as Bob clarified, you've transposed the output.

Comment: @jaked swap cols and rows while calling `is_visible` and `is_ship` like in: is_visible(  **col_index, row_index** )

Comment: Hey, @Bob__... it's a mission.. don't make it TOO easy! ;)

Comment: @Bob__ Thanks! Just did it before you added the latest comment. Not sure why I didn't notice the flipping...